# React Native import GoogleMaps key into build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, build.gradle

Would it be possible to import the Google Maps key from a JS or JSON file for use in build.gradle?

```
manifestPlaceholders = [GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: "$config.js.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY"]
```